# "/" getting replaced with space in background url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using pageflip plugin for my website. when I give hard coded url of background image , it works fine  as below.

but when I use dynamic url from db as below,

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$imgn=$row["IMG"]; ?>

<div class=page page-current style=background: #209657 url('<?php echo $imgn; ?>')  no-repeat center center; background-size: 850px 750px;></div>";

<?php   }?>
```

if : $imgn=$row["IMG"]; as $imgn=promotion/5.jpg; 
 is substituted as below,
Then when it is used as background url,

```
<div class="page" page-current style="display: block;" #209657 url('promotions"" 3.jpg') no-repeat center center; background-size: 850px 750px;></div>
```

promotions/3.jpg converted as 'promotions="" 3.jpg'. can any one suggest me idea for solving this?

Comment: fix your html for use with double quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't your actual output HTML.  That's what the DOM browser in your developer tools looks like.

Your actual HTML isn't valid.  You need to quote your attribute values

```
<div class="page page-current" style="background: #209657 ...
```

If you want to see what your PHP code is actually generating, right click and hit "view source".

Also, be sure to use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data used in the context of HTML, to make sure you are escaping any special characters correctly.

Comment: Great. Thank you  so much.